# Measuring time according to CPU clock?

Tags: java, performance

I have read in a few low latency technical papers that they measured timings via the CPU, as it is more accurate.

Usually in Java I would use:

```
System.nanoTime()
```

and in C++ I believe I once used a performance counter method which I found online that could do accuracy to nanoseconds. It used a LARGE_INTEGER, was assigned to the accuracy you wish to measure and then was passed by reference to QueryPerformanceCounter() and returned an answer divided by the frequency.

Is there any Java equivalent code to measure time according to the CPU, or would one have to use some sort of PInvoke?

EDIT:

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdisruptor.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FDisruptor-1.0.pdf&ei=ImmQT5WQMOaW0QWW2sTwAQ&usg=AFQjCNEeGmYXzJa8huMdRGN2p4n8YH-jfg

> To time at this level of precision it is necessary to use time stamp
>   counters from the CPU. We chose CPUs with an invariant TSC because
>   older processors suffer from changing frequency due to power saving
>   and sleep states.

I'm interested in answers for Windows and Linux, but would appreciate if people could explain if their answer is specific to one.

Comment: Minor nit: it's actually System.nanoTime()

Comment: ...and it's a native method, so I'd venture to say it probably uses QueryPerformanceCounter()/QueryPerformanceFrequency() inside.

Comment: @Alan, I actually looked it up and thought I had corrected it- obviously not.

Comment: @Alan, it declares a LARGE_INTEGER, accepts the accuracy you wish to measure and then passed this by reference to QueryPerformanceCounter() and returns an answer divided by the frequency. I would love to know what the Java-possible technique is?

Comment: if that's the case, and System.nanoTime() isn't good enough as is, you need to PInvoke into C/C++, which kind of defeats the purpose of obtaining greater accuracy. But I'm not a Java expert (that's why I keep this as a comment), so there may well be a better option.

Comment: sorry for no addressing, the comment system eats up my @'s at the front...

Comment: what are you trying to time?  Are you trying to micro-benchmark?  If so, there are several problems with micro-benchmarking which can throw your results off if you do not take them into account.  A tool like Caliper helps address some (but not all) of those issues.

Comment: @Kevin, depending on your definition of micro-benchmarking, yes. I am just asking generally how to time code to high accuracy/precision in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.nanoTime() can be have a fast nano-second resolution timer depending on the OS.  On some OSes this is as fast at 20 ns.

In this library I have use RDTSC because RHEL 5.x is not one of those OS where its fast. :( https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity It takes less than 10 ns on a fast PC.

The problem with using the cpu counter is that its different on different sockets. If your program only runs on one socket, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Micro-benchmarking has several inherent variables that might be overlooked

- Java effect of garbage collection
- Java effects of JIT optimizations which take some time to "warm up"
- Java target VM
- Java VM settings (-Xnnnn settings, as well as client vs server mode)
- target OS differences
- target CPU differences
- quiescence: how busy is the CPU  multi-tasking other things in the background
- overhead of the benchmark code itself

A tool like the [Caliper Micro-benchmarking framework](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) attempts to address some but not all of the above issues.  I am not even certain of everything it is attempting to do.  But at least the main obvious things it does is to attempt to warm up the JIT, run the benchmark code a fixed number of times and average over the iterations, and repeat that exercise several times until there is some acceptable tolerance difference between runs.  It also captures and records the environment so that future benchmarks may compare apples to apples (instead of oranges).  And it allows you to repeat and compare all of the above with different VM settings or program arguments easily, and compare the results of each.

That said, it is still a tricky peril-fraught endeavor to not misinterpret the results, or more likely to not let *somebody else* misinterpret the results.

**EDIT** (Addition)
Actually the JIT can cut both ways.  While you generally want the JIT to be warmed up, it can also optimize away things that you want to include as part of the benchmark.  So you have to write your benchmark in such a way to anticipate and prevent things like loop invariants from being optimized away by forcing each loop to actually vary in the ways that are important/significant to what you are measuring.